Inverse of the identity minus a block anti-diagonal matrix.
Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ be an $n\times m$ matrix. Denote by $C$ the square block matrix given by
$$
C=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & B\\
A & 0
\end{array}\right].
$$
I am looking for the inverse
$$
D=\left(I-C\right)^{-1}
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. There are some nice equations for the inverse of $2\times 2$ block matrices and for block diagonal matrices, but I'm not sure how to tackle matrices like $I-C$. (see also how to invert anti-diagonal block matrices)

The matrix $I-C$ is a block matrix with 2 invertible matrices on the diagonal. You can use the equation that you are linking to by substituting an $I$ of the appropriate size for $A$ and $D$, $-A$ for $B$ and $-B$ for $C.$

Duh, not sure why I didn't see that. Thank you!

Sorry, had to apply a correction because I mixed up the letters
